# Label QGIS points layer with auto incrementing number count from 1

Tags: qgis, labeling, point

I have imported a CSV layer to my map and want to label the points with a numeric count from 1 upwards, counting just the visible points.

I have almost found a way to do this using the HouseNumbering plugin to automatically create a number count in a field (having converted the table from CSV to SHP file)

However I need to create maps of several different area views which each need to be numbered from 1, so will need multiple different fields with different numberings in the attribute table, and then swap labels depending on which view I'm in - which is messy

Is there a way to create an incremented count 'on the fly' without it needing to be in the attribute table?

The closest I can find is to label with $id which doesnt' work as the numbers don't start from 1 on my specific map view
Or $uuid which labels the points with a 38 characters unique string (not very attractive!)